# the basic if-else statement

Tags: java, if-statement

I'm taking the if-else statement this week and I trying to solve the question but I'm still getting an error message. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Remember that this is an `if-else` question but other methods will be also appreciated.

> Clunker Motors Inc. is recalling all vehicles from model years 1995-1998 and 2004-2006. Given a variable modelYear write a statement that prints the message `RECALL` to standard output if the value of modelYear falls within those two ranges.

```
if(modelYear==1995||modelYear==1998)
{
    System.out.println("Recall");   
}
else if(modelYear==2004||modelYear==2006)
{
    System.out.println("Recall");
}
```

Comment: So, what's the question?

Comment: do you get compilation error?

Comment: @Preet Kukreti Please note that [the homework tag is now being phased out and must no longer be used](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Clunker Motors Inc. is recalling all vehicles from model years 1995-1998 and 2004-2006

it means that models from [1995, 1996, 1997, 1998] and [2004, 2005, 2006], these years should be recalled.

Your condition:

```
if(modelYear==1995||modelYear==1998)
```

means that only two years in range are counted. models from [1996 and 1997] won't be recalled.

To include both the ranges you can do following:

```
if ((modelYear>=1995 && modelYear<=1998) || (modelYear>=2004 && modelYear<=2006))
{
    System.out.println("Recall");
}
```

OR

You should create a separate method to check the ranges:

```
boolean isYearWithinRange(int modelYear, int start, int end)
{
    return modelYear>=start && modelYear<=end;
}

if(isYearWithinRange(modelYear, 1995, 1998) || isYearWithinRange(modelYear, 2004, 2006))
{
    System.out.println("Recall");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (modelYear==1995||modelYear==1998)
```

means if the year is 1995 **or** 1998 only. so the year 1996 and 1997 will not pass.

If you replace the statement with:

```
if (modelYear>=1995 && modelYear<=1998)
```

then you are expressing a range between 1995 and 1998 inclusive. This statement is true for only the integers [1995, 1996, 1997, 1998]. Note the switch from logical OR (`||`) to logical AND (`&&`) which means both comparison checks must be true for the conditional expression to return `true`.

Comment: I gave an explanation also... I dont think it was particularly lazy.

Comment: given the level of his exercise, he can copy, paste, see that it works, move to the next one.

Comment: Yes, but he/she will have to apply it to the other half of the example, which at the very least will require a modicum of thinking/substitution. At this ultra basic level, it is hard to know what to expect/assume about their knowledge. Do they know about the comparison operators? do they know logical AND? etc etc. I'd hope they do, but considering this is not a realtime/chatbased communications interface, the bit-by-bit hints dont work well in a one-shot answer format.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check for year *ranges*. What you are doing right now is testing for exact year *values*

Answer (score -1):

```
if(modelYear>=1995 && modelYear<=1998)
{
  System.out.println("Recall");   
}
else if(modelYear>=2004 && modelYear<=2006)
{
  System.out.println("Recall");
}
```